# How to assign two IP addresses (one DHCP, one static) to a NIC in OpenSolaris?

Tags: networking, opensolaris, nic, ipv4

This should be mind-numbingly simple and basic, and yet I couldn't find how to do it, either in "man ifconfig", in the [OpenSolaris docs site](http://dlc.sun.com/osol/docs/content/2009.06), or Googling in desperation. I'm using OpenSolaris 2009.06.

When I try `ifconfig e1000g0:0 10.10.10.1 netmask 255.0.0.0 up` all addresses go kablooie instead. This happen whether the network is in "automatic" or "manual" mode.

Alternatively, I could use a way to set up two static IP addresses too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ifconfig e1000g0:1 blah...` or `ifconfig e1000g0 addif 10.10.10.1/16` instead - IIRC the zero alias/logical interface is special on Solaris.

Comment: "ifconfig e1000g0 addif" worked! Thanks!